# Buscar el elemento más cercano con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un set de inputs con sus respectivos divs. Lo que necesito es que mientras escribo, se replique lo que escribo en el div más cercano. He intentado usar `closest() next() parent() siglings()` pero ninguno funciona.

Como puedo hacerlo?

```js
$(function(){

  $(document).on('keyup','.foo',function(){
    let val = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('.bar').html(val);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="foo">
<div class="bar"></div>

<input class="foo">
<div class="bar"></div>

<input class="foo">
<div class="bar"></div>

<input class="foo">
<div class="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplemente con `.next()` pasandole de parámetro el selector.

```js
$(function(){

  $(document).on('keyup','.foo',function(){
    let val = $(this).val();
    $(this).next('.bar').html(val);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="foo">
<div class="bar"></div>

<input class="foo">
<div class="bar"></div>

<input class="foo">
<div class="bar"></div>

<input class="foo">
<div class="bar"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias sensei, no sabía que next() recibía parámetros.